# Keyboard shortcut to switch applications (Alt+Tab) isn't working

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

In Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit, the keyboard shortcut to switch applications (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)is not working

I have done a Full Update/Upgrade.
Keyboard Layout: US
Format: US
Input Source: US
GUI: Gnome Classic

Does any know how to fix this?

Comment: Bug report filed regarding this - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/971051

Comment: They messed this up, too? 12.04 also cast super+t permanently to opening the recycle bin. :P I use Autokey-Qt for lots of text-entry macros. Indispensable with heavy email traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround until the bug is addressed:

1. Install & run ccsm:

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager && ccsm`
2. Enable 'Application Switcher' under 'Window Management'

This worked for me

(*note that I'm using Linux Mint 13 Maya + 'Gnome Classic' session*)

Answer (score 1):

Launch the "keyboard" app from the Dash, and go to the "Shortcuts" tab. See if your shortcut is well configured.

It is located under the "Navigation" category and named as "Switch applications".

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already did, and assign Alt + TAB, among other combinations and does not work, works seamlessly in 10.04.

Comment: Are you using Unity 2D? I'm using Unity 2D with an Nvidia card that can't run 3D, and I've lost several times shortcut combinations (ALT-TAB among them) after gconfd process hangs, eats up all CPU and I had to manually kill it. Reassign them worked for me. Can you try with a fresh new user?

Answer (score 0):

Download and run CCSM. After opening it, go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher (top tab) > Key to start the switcher

Erase/edit whatever keys it says there (change it to anything else). Then click on the right button to Reset it to Tab.

If that doesn't work, you definitely have a system bug, or a faulty keyboard.